# What database model should be used with a bunch of different items?

Tags: json, postgresql, relational-database

Ok, so I have a site in which you have items. These items are different but have some common properties and I would like to store them in the database. I'm using a relational database and I'm not sure which type of subclass style that should be used here. E/R-style causes very hard and long queries, null-style creates lots of nulls and a third option is too store some data in just a json-string in some column, thus the database does not have to be altered when I add a new item. What do you think?

Comment: For this kind of requirement, a JSON column is indeed the best solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You think so? It would simplify things, only down-side is that I feel its "quick and dirty", is it common do that?